# Is it possible to Generate database documents in Oracle SQL Developer, using the Schema, rather than as the logged in user?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

When right clicking the connection and clicking *Generate DB Docs*, everything works fine, but the issue is that it doesn't show objects because I do not own any in the Server. I am a reader, who uses the data daily.

What I'd like is the ability to generate the same HTML file or even a PDF from a Schema perspective, rather than from a logged in user perspective.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If not possible in the SQL Developer, are there any free applications that I could use to generate this type of documentation? Doesn't have to be the same format.

[This screenshot shows where in the Oracle SQL Developer I am referring to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrYAd.png)

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server if its Oracle you are interested in?

Comment: Use the data Modeler, you can import any schema and build html data dictionary reports

Comment: Thanks thatjeffsmith. That’s the route I took.